# PortalSiteMapProvider

Tags: sharepoint, portalsitemapprovider

Everytime I instantiate a PortalSiteMapProvider instance it always defaults to the Root Web Site Collection.

I want to be able to acquire a site map from a different collection from an application page.

Because of this, the context defaults to the root web since this application page resides under _layouts and is not hosted under any site collection.

How do I acquire an instance to a site collection other than the root web from an application page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't read another site collection's hierarchy through a PortalSiteMapProvider. E.g., if you are in Site Collection A, PSMP will only traverse A's tree, not B. You have to be in B to traverse B.

A workaround I implemented was to write a simple web service that runs in a site collection and takes a path as a parameter. It reads its own PSMP and writes an XML tree from that point in the hierarchy. Calling the web service living in SC-B from code running in SC-A is extremely fast, especially since the PSMP can rip through B's structure so quickly.

**Edit:**

[Here are instructions for creating a web service in WSS3/MOSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx).

Here is some totally non-functional code to get you headed in the right direction:

```
//method exposed through the web service
public XmlDocument GetTree(string path)
{
    PortalSiteMapProvider psmp = PortalSiteMapProvider.GlobalNavSiteMapProvider;
    SiteMapNode node = psmp.FindSiteMapNode(path);
    return BuildXmlFromNode(node);
}

private XmlNode BuildXmlFromNode(SiteMapNode node)
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    reutrn BuildXmlFromNode(node, xml);
}

//recurses down the sitemapnode children
private XmlNode BuildXmlFromNode(SiteMapNode node, XmlNode xml)
{
    XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement("Node")
    element.SetAttribute("title", node.Title);
    element.SetAttribute("url", node.Url);

    xml.AppendChild(element);

    foreach(SiteMapNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        BuildXmlFromNode(childNode, element);
    }

    return xml;
}
```

**Please note** if you don't set a limit on the number of recursions and your site map hierarchy is very deep and/or wide, this could produce a HUGE xml document. Use with caution!

Comment: You mind helping me out with writing a simple webservice? I've never done it before. Any pointer to steer me in that direction? Thanks!

Comment: @LB no problem; see additions to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much Appreciated! This should get me started.